# android respond to contact > send?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm looking for the magic incantation to make my app respond to contact > send. i want to be able to receive the contact's URI in order to retrieve the contact. would anyone have the manifest filter / code snippet for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not testes, but you could try an Intent filter that is based on  `ACTION_SEND` and mime type vcard. Once again, not tested:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, sort of. what i saw is that the receiver sees that data as a file:// URI, pointing to a file in /sdcard/System where a .vcffile was written. so now i need a .vcf parser :(

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is the expected result :) Gmail and MMS will simply send this vcard file as an attachment